# How to re-insulate between roof and top floor?

Tags: insulation

The space between my roof and the ceiling of my 2nd (top-most) floor is barely enough for me to crawl in. The roof tapers down to either end of the house from that, making the outer reaches inaccessible (by me, at least). How can I get insulation up in there, so that the outer perimeter of the roof is well insulated?

Comment: What's in there now? Is there soffit venting in place?